# Can we sum a series over noninteger bounds?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, mathematical-physics

Are there any ways to generalize series to noninteger bounds? For example, is there any way to make sense of
$$
f(\nu)=\sum_{k=\nu}^\infty a_k
$$
for $\nu\in\Bbb C$? I would expect that if such a generalization exists, it should obey have the same properties as the case where $\nu$ is an integer.  In particular, I would expect it to obey the recurrence relation
$$
f(\nu)-f(\nu+1)=a_\nu.
$$

Comment: This question can be answered using the methods of [summability calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5739).  In short, there are ways to define sums involving noninteger bounds.  You are on the right track to claim the second term would be evaluated at $x=e+1$.

Answer (score 1):

We find in chapter 2 *Sums* of  *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by R.L. Graham, D.E.  Knuth  and O.  Patashnik the following statement (see formula 2.4):

> Formally, we write
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{P(k)} a_k\tag{2.4}
> \end{align*}
> as an abbreviation for the sum of all terms $a_k$ such that $k$  is an integer satisfying a given property $P(k)$. (A property $P(k)$ is any statement about $k$ that can be either true or false.)

We see the index $k$ is an integer. Sometimes we have the situation that the upper limit of a sum is not an integer. In this situation we take the greatest integer less or equal to the upper limit (*[floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)*).
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} a_k=\sum_{k=0}^{\color{blue}{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}} a_k=a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}
\end{align*}

Similarly the lower limit is sometimes not an integer. In this situation we take the smallest integer greater or equal to the lower limit
(*[ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)*).
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=\frac{m}{2}}^{\frac{n}{2}} a_k=\sum_{k=\color{blue}{\left\lceil\frac{m}{2}\right\rceil}}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} a_k=a_{\left\lceil\frac{m}{2}\right\rceil}+a_{\left\lceil\frac{m}{2}\right\rceil+1}+\cdots+a_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}
\end{align*}

> If the lower limit of the index is equal to $e$, we have consequently
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=e}^\infty a_k=\sum_{k=\left\lceil e\right\rceil}^\infty a_k=\sum_{\color{blue}{k=3}}^\infty a_k
> \end{align*}

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could write something like
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty f(e + n)
$$

Comment: What if $f$ is $1/n$  so that $n=0$ will not work?

Comment: In case $f=\frac{1}{n}$ you have $\frac{1}{e+n}$, so $n=0$ works.

Comment: @jordan-g I am afraid I don't understand your comment. Could you rephrase your question by giving a concrete example?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4091331/make-the-summation-element-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-cdot-e-to-be

Comment: @jordan-g I just posted an answer to your other question. I hope it helps.