# Make the summation element of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot e}$ to be $ \frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, mathematical-physics

If I want the summation element of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot e}$$ to be $ \frac{1}{n}$ and completely eliminate $e$, is the following solution correct?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot e}$$
$$\sum_{\frac{n}{e}=\frac{1}{e}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{n}{e} \cdot e}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Why didn't you edit your previous question instead of posting a new one?

Comment: What micmac are you trying to achieve? Just factor out the constant $\sum \text{cst}\cdot a_n=\text{cst}\sum a_n$ (not that it is useful in the present case since the series diverges, but ok).

Comment: You have an arithmetic mistake, one big conceptual mistake and its all wrapped in working with a divergent sum. You cannot make *any* substitution you want in a sum, you are basically restricted to integer shifts (e.g. you can change $n\to n-2$ and sum over $3,4,5,\ldots$). The summation variable has to be an integer and substituting $n' = n/e$ this is no longer the case (also the sum would be over $n/e=1,2,3,\ldots$ not $1/e,2/e$). Even if you could do this then you are still manipulating something that is divergent to start with so the manipulations you do don't have any real meaning.

Answer (score 2):

No. That series diverges, since it is the harmonic series times a non-zero constant (and also because the harmonic series diverges).

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on zwim 's comment, one has, for all positive integer $k$,
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{1}{n \cdot e} = \frac{1}{e} \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}
$$
When $k$ tends to $\infty$, the right hand side diverges, and hence so is the left hand side.